# Linux kernel version cause Network latency increasing

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel

I'm measuring the ping-pong latency between two machines, both are `20.04.1-Ubuntu`.

My ping-pong latency: The sender sends a udp pkt to the receiver, and the receiver sends a udp pkt back instantly. When the sender receives the pkt this round will end.

At first, I used the `5.4.0-100-generic`, measured average latency is `13.632 us`.

Later, I updated the kernel to `5.15.0-41-generic`, and measured the average latency as `20.141 us`.

The setup of the rest of the system is the same, and I ran the code multiple times. I wonder is it the problem with linux kernel or I make some mistakes?

Here is my code on the `sender` side(you can just pay attention to the logic in `main`), as for the receiver, I added it in the notation:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <linux/errqueue.h>
#include <linux/net_tstamp.h>
#include <linux/sockios.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>


#define UDP_MAX_LENGTH 1500
#define WARM_UP_PACKETS 10000
#define TOTAL_PACKETS 1000000

long arr2[TOTAL_PACKETS + 5];


typedef struct {
    int fd;
    int port;
    int err_no;
    struct sockaddr_in local;
    struct sockaddr_in remote;
    struct timeval time_kernel;
    struct timeval time_user;
    int64_t prev_serialnum;
} socket_info;

typedef struct {
    int64_t serialnum;

    int64_t user_time_serialnum;
    int64_t user_time;

    int64_t kernel_time_serialnum;
    int64_t kernel_time;

    size_t message_bytes;
} message_header;


static int setup_udp_sender(socket_info *inf, int port, char *address) {
    inf->port = port;
    inf->fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (inf->fd < 0) {
        inf->err_no = errno;
        fprintf(stderr, "setup_udp_client: socket failed: %s\n",
                strerror(inf->err_no));
        return inf->fd;
    }

    int timestampOn =
        SOF_TIMESTAMPING_RX_SOFTWARE | SOF_TIMESTAMPING_TX_SOFTWARE |
        SOF_TIMESTAMPING_SOFTWARE | SOF_TIMESTAMPING_RX_HARDWARE |
        SOF_TIMESTAMPING_TX_HARDWARE | SOF_TIMESTAMPING_RAW_HARDWARE |
        // SOF_TIMESTAMPING_OPT_TSONLY |
        0;
    int r = setsockopt(inf->fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_TIMESTAMPING, &timestampOn,
                        sizeof timestampOn);
    if (r < 0) {
        inf->err_no = errno;
        fprintf(stderr, "setup_udp_server: setsockopt failed: %s\n",
                strerror(inf->err_no));
        return r;
    }

    inf->remote = (struct sockaddr_in){.sin_family = AF_INET,
                                        .sin_port = htons((uint16_t)port)};
    r = inet_aton(address, &inf->remote.sin_addr);
    if (r == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "setup_udp_client: inet_aton failed\n");
        inf->err_no = 0;
        return -1;
    }

    inf->local = (struct sockaddr_in){.sin_family = AF_INET,
                                        .sin_port = htons(0),
                                        .sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY)};
    inf->prev_serialnum = -1;

    return 0;
}
static int setup_udp_receiver(socket_info *inf, int port) {
    inf->port = port;
    inf->fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (inf->fd < 0) {
        inf->err_no = errno;
        fprintf(stderr, "setup_udp_server: socket failed: %s\n",
                strerror(inf->err_no));
        return inf->fd;
    }

    int timestampOn =
        SOF_TIMESTAMPING_RX_SOFTWARE | SOF_TIMESTAMPING_TX_SOFTWARE |
        SOF_TIMESTAMPING_SOFTWARE | SOF_TIMESTAMPING_RX_HARDWARE |
        SOF_TIMESTAMPING_TX_HARDWARE | SOF_TIMESTAMPING_RAW_HARDWARE |
        // SOF_TIMESTAMPING_OPT_TSONLY |
        0;
    int r = setsockopt(inf->fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_TIMESTAMPING, &timestampOn,
                        sizeof timestampOn);
    if (r < 0) {
        inf->err_no = errno;
        fprintf(stderr, "setup_udp_server: setsockopt failed: %s\n",
                strerror(inf->err_no));
        return r;
    }

    int on = 1;
    r = setsockopt(inf->fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &on, sizeof on);
    if (r < 0) {
        inf->err_no = errno;
        fprintf(stderr, "setup_udp_server: setsockopt2 failed: %s\n",
                strerror(inf->err_no));
        return r;
    }

    inf->local = (struct sockaddr_in){.sin_family = AF_INET,
                                        .sin_port = htons((uint16_t)port),
                                        .sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY)};
    r = bind(inf->fd, (struct sockaddr *)&inf->local, sizeof inf->local);
    if (r < 0) {
        inf->err_no = errno;
        fprintf(stderr, "setup_udp_server: bind failed: %s\n",
                strerror(inf->err_no));
        return r;
    }

    inf->prev_serialnum = -1;

    return 0;
}

static void handle_scm_timestamping(struct scm_timestamping *ts) {
    struct timespec cur;
    if( clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &cur) == -1 ) {
      perror( "clock gettime" );
      exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    // printf("pkt: timestamp: %ld.%ld ns\n", ts->ts[0].tv_sec, ts->ts[0].tv_nsec);
    // printf("now: timestamp: %ld.%ld ns\n\n", cur.tv_sec, cur.tv_nsec);
    // printf("Latency: %.3f us\n\n\n", (cur.tv_nsec - ) * 0.001);
    // printf("timestamp: %ld ns\n", ts->ts[0].tv_nsec);

    static int count = 0;
    ++count;
    if (count > WARM_UP_PACKETS) {
        // arr[++arr[0]] = end.tv_sec * 1000000000LL + end.tv_nsec - start.tv_sec * 1000000000LL - start.tv_nsec;
        arr2[++arr2[0]] = ts->ts[0].tv_sec * 1000000000LL + ts->ts[0].tv_nsec;
    }

    // for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof ts->ts / sizeof *ts->ts; i++) {
    //     printf("timestamp: %lld.%.9lds\n", (long long)ts->ts[i].tv_sec,
    //         ts->ts[i].tv_nsec);
    // }
    // puts("\n");
}

static void handle_time(struct msghdr *msg) {
    for (struct cmsghdr *cmsg = CMSG_FIRSTHDR(msg); cmsg; cmsg = CMSG_NXTHDR(msg, cmsg)) {
        // printf("level=%d, type=%d, len=%zu\n", cmsg->cmsg_level, cmsg->cmsg_type, cmsg->cmsg_len);

        if (cmsg->cmsg_level == SOL_IP && cmsg->cmsg_type == IP_RECVERR) {
            struct sock_extended_err *ext =
                (struct sock_extended_err *)CMSG_DATA(cmsg);
            printf("errno=%d, origin=%d\n", ext->ee_errno, ext->ee_origin);
            continue;
        }

        if (cmsg->cmsg_level != SOL_SOCKET) continue;

        switch (cmsg->cmsg_type) {
            case SO_TIMESTAMPNS: {
                struct scm_timestamping *ts = (struct scm_timestamping *)CMSG_DATA(cmsg);
                handle_scm_timestamping(ts);
            } break;
            case SO_TIMESTAMPING: {
                struct scm_timestamping *ts = (struct scm_timestamping *)CMSG_DATA(cmsg);
                handle_scm_timestamping(ts);
            } break;
            default:
            /* Ignore other cmsg options */
            break;
        }
    }
    // printf("End messages\n");
}

static ssize_t udp_receive(socket_info *inf, char *buf, size_t len) {
    char ctrl[2048];
    struct iovec iov = (struct iovec){.iov_base = buf, .iov_len = len};
    struct msghdr msg = (struct msghdr){.msg_control = ctrl,
                                        .msg_controllen = sizeof ctrl,
                                        .msg_name = &inf->remote,
                                        .msg_namelen = sizeof inf->remote,
                                        .msg_iov = &iov,
                                        .msg_iovlen = 1};
    ssize_t recv_len = recvmsg(inf->fd, &msg, 0);
    gettimeofday(&inf->time_user, NULL);

    if (recv_len < 0) {
        inf->err_no = errno;
        fprintf(stderr, "udp_receive: recvfrom failed: %s\n",
                strerror(inf->err_no));
    }

    // printf("length: %d\n", );

    // handle_time(&msg);

    return recv_len;
}

static const size_t payload_max = UDP_MAX_LENGTH - sizeof(message_header);

char type_str[50] = "specpaxos.vr.proto.PrepareMessage";
static ssize_t generate_random_message(socket_info *inf, char *buf,
                                       size_t len) {
    size_t payload_len = 10;

    buf[0] = 0x18, buf[1] = 0x03, buf[2] = 0x05, buf[3] = 0x20;
    buf[4] = 0x21;
    int x = 5;
    for(; x < 12; ++x) buf[x] = 0x00;
    for(int i = 0; i < 33; ++i) buf[x + i] = type_str[i];
    x += 33;
    buf[x++] = 0x18;
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; ++i, ++x) buf[x] = 0x00;
    for(int i = 0; i < 24; ++i, ++x) buf[x] = 0x00;

    buf[x++] = 0x02;
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; ++i, ++x) buf[x] = 0x00;
    buf[x++] = 0x00;
    buf[x++] = 0x00;

    return (ssize_t)x;
}


static socket_info registerReceiver(void) {
    socket_info inf;
    int ret = setup_udp_receiver(&inf, 12345);
    if (ret < 0) {
        exit(-1);
    }
    return inf;
}

static ssize_t udp_send(socket_info *inf, char *buf, size_t len) {
    struct iovec iov = (struct iovec){.iov_base = buf, .iov_len = len};
    struct msghdr msg = (struct msghdr){.msg_name = &inf->remote,
                                        .msg_namelen = sizeof inf->remote,
                                        .msg_iov = &iov,
                                        .msg_iovlen = 1};
    gettimeofday(&inf->time_user, NULL);
    ssize_t send_len = sendmsg(inf->fd, &msg, 0);
    if (send_len < 0) {
        inf->err_no = errno;
        fprintf(stderr, "udp_send: sendmsg failed: %s\n", strerror(inf->err_no));
    }

    return send_len;
}

ssize_t send_packet(socket_info inf) {
    char packet_buffer[4096];
    struct timespec cur;
    ssize_t len = generate_random_message(&inf, packet_buffer, sizeof packet_buffer);
    
    return udp_send(&inf, packet_buffer, (size_t)len);
}



static socket_info registerSender(char *host) {
    socket_info inf;
    int ret = setup_udp_sender(&inf, 12345, host);
    if (ret < 0) {
        exit(-1);
    }
    return inf;
}


long arr[TOTAL_PACKETS + 5];
int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b) {
   return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}
void queryStatistic() {
    int n = arr[0];
    qsort(arr + 1, n, sizeof(arr[0]), cmpfunc);
    double sum = 0.0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) sum += arr[i];

    printf("Average latency: %.3f\n", sum / n * 0.001);
    printf("90th tail latency: %.3f\n", arr[(long)(n * 0.9)] * 0.001);
    printf("99th tail latency: %.3f\n", arr[(long)(n * 0.99)] * 0.001);
    printf("99.9th tail latency: %.3f\n", arr[(long)(n * 0.999)] * 0.001);
}



int main(void) {
    socket_info inf_tx, inf_rx;
    inf_tx = registerSender("10.10.1.3");
    inf_rx = registerReceiver();

    int count = 0;
    
    char packet_buffer[4096];
    struct timespec start, end;
    uint64_t next_send_tick = 0;
    /* for receiver:
    while (1) {
        udp_receive(&inf_rx, packet_buffer, sizeof packet_buffer);
        send_packet(inf_tx);      
    }
    */
    while(1) {
        // printf("asd123www\n");
        struct timespec time = {0, 0};
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &time);
        uint64_t tick = time.tv_sec * 1000000000LL + time.tv_nsec;
        if(tick >= next_send_tick) {

            clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);
            send_packet(inf_tx);
            udp_receive(&inf_rx, packet_buffer, sizeof packet_buffer);
            clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &end);

            ++count;
            if (count > WARM_UP_PACKETS) {
                arr[++arr[0]] = end.tv_sec * 1000000000LL + end.tv_nsec - start.tv_sec * 1000000000LL - start.tv_nsec;
                // arr[++arr[0]] = end.tv_sec * 1000000000LL + end.tv_nsec;
            }
            // printf("%ld\n", arr[arr[0]]);

            // printf("%.3f\n", (end.tv_sec * 1000000000LL + end.tv_nsec - start.tv_sec * 1000000000LL - start.tv_nsec) * 0.001);
            next_send_tick = tick + 1500; 

            if (count == TOTAL_PACKETS) break;
        }
    }
    // for(int i = 1; i <= arr[0]; ++i) arr[i] -= arr2[i];

    queryStatistic();
}
```

Comment: How (what tools / calculus) you use to measure that latentcy.? Irq pinning identical (5.4 vs 5.15) ? irqbalance daemont running ? irqthreaded ? network phy interrupts coalesced ?… Well… you should actually tell much much more.

Comment: Thanks, I will share my code.

Comment: And of course, you took care to pin this task on cpu different from the one handling the network device irq. BTW you did not answer regarding the irqbalance daemon & about running irqthreaded. My point being : If you do not care about all this, latency is just unpredictable. Not deterministic. At least first compute the stdev too, you will know more in the meaningfulness of the average.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I used `taskset -c` to pin my task. But I did miss the irq. I did find that sometimes the results from two measurements are quite different. It's a really good suggestion and I'll check the stdev.

Comment: This is the latest kernel update? Coming out not long after the retbleed disaster, if that is all you've lost, then you should be grateful!

Comment: Yes, now I changed to kernel version 5.8.0, which behaves similarly to 5.4.0